# Neo4j Desktop DB failed to start with with status 'KILLED'

Tags: database, neo4j, desktop-application

Running Neo4j Desktop version 1.0.15. Trying to start DB causes the start fail:

> Database failed to start:
>   DB [database-f8950fdd-6b5f-4fea-8c9f-e8457ee1da9a] 'v3.3.1' exited
>   with status 'KILLED'. Check the logs

Major Log parts are below

```
2018-02-26 23:03:38.004+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6411d3c8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Connection timed out: connect". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6411d3c8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Connection timed out: connect".

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, C:\Users\kiril\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-f8950fdd-6b5f-4fea-8c9f-e8457ee1da9a\installation-3.3.1\data\databases\graph.db

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.backup.OnlineBackupKernelExtension@c6e0f32' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Connection timed out: connect".

    Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Exception during graceful attempt to stop partially started component. Please use non suppressed exception to see original component failure.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
```

Comment: I got this error 3 times in a row, and then without changing anything, it started just fine on the fourth try (while I was still searching for a real solution).  It's just the standard buggy behavior and poor support we have come to expect from Neo4j.

Comment: Ran into something very similar, going to cross-link because this was the first hit I got when I was searching for answers, mine was a [java process that got left running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529386/ran-into-error-while-try-to-start-new-graph-instance-on-neo4j-desktop)  It got downvoted already which I was a little confused about.  Anyway, hope it helps another lost soul.

Answer (score 1):

It might be your neo4j was still running.
I solved this problem by shutting down the database and restarting it.

Platform: Windows 10; 
Neo4j Desktop version: 1.1.13

Open a commend-line window and go to the directory of your neo4j database.
run

```
bin\neo4j status
```

to check the status of your database.

If it is running, run

```
bin\neo4j stop
```

to shut down your database.
Then go back to the Neo4j Desktop, click the start button, and it could be symptom-free.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the issue was resolved when I cloned the graph I was connecting. Thereafter, I could connect to the new graph without any problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing helped me is the program reinstall